Hibernate Audit times incorrect nanos
When I'm updating the object gets updated correctly but the audit table looses the nano correctness.
So for example I create the object with time 2024-11-13 15:39:06.9320892 +00:00
In the Object table it is always 2024-11-13 15:39:06.9320892 +00:00
But in the Object_History table just the first audit line is 2024-11-13 15:39:06.9320892 +00:00, the rest have CreatedDate "2024-11-13 15:39:06.0093209 +00:00"
How can I fix this or set it up better?
    @Audited
    @AuditTable(schema = "hist", value = "Object_History")
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Object", schema = "dbo")
    @DynamicUpdate
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EntityListeners(AuditEntityListener.class)

Where AuditEntityListener sets the Created and Updated Date
    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist(AbstractEntity entity) {
        if (entity.getCreatedDate() == null) {
            entity.setCreatedDate(OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
        }
        entity.setModifiedDate(OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
    }
    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate(AbstractEntity entity) {
        if (entity.getCreatedDate() == null) {
            entity.setCreatedDate(OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
        }
        entity.setModifiedDate(OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()));
    }

I have an application in Java 17 with Hibernate envers version 6.4.4 and Hibernate c3p0 version 0.9.5.5

Any reason why you are using OffsetDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()) instead of Instant.now()?
